# Como recorrer una tabla de HTML con JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html, datatable

Buenas tardes programadores, estoy intentando recorrer una tabla de HTML con JAVASCRIPT para actualizar diversos estados de la informacion que contendra, pero no logro dar al clavo.

Esta esta es mi tabla en HTML

```
        <table class="rwd-table" id="rwd-table-id">
            <tr>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Apellido</th>
                <th>Estado</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="name">Juan</td>
                <td id="apellido">Perez</td>
                <td id="status">Online</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="name">Pedro</td>
                <td id="apellido">Lopez</td>
                <td id="status">Online</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="name">Antonia</td>
                <td id="apellido">Sandoval</td>
                <td id="status">Online</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Esta es mi funcion de javascript

```
    try{
        var resume_table = document.getElementById("rwd-table-id");
        
        for (var i = 0, cell; cell = resume_table[i]; i++) {
            alert("Valor Celda: " + cell[i].innerText);
        }
    }
    catch(error)
    {
        alert('Error processing document ' + console.error(error));
    }
```

Agradezco las respuestas constructivas

Comment: Podrías adjuntar una imágen de la tabla y explicar qué es lo que quieres realizar exactamente y detalladamente, para poderte ayudar.

Comment: Por ejemplo, quiero poner el numero 1 en amarillo y el Online en verde. Pero para eso debo de recorrer la tabla completamente con un ciclo for el cual me esta dando problemas...

Comment: Que error te muestra? al parecer el for es el que no tiene bien definidos los parámetros

Comment: el catch del try me dice 'undefined'

Comment: En ambos ciclos estás recorriendo `cells`, el primero debería ser por `rows`.

Comment: Actualice el codigo para que sea mas leible, solo quiero obtener el valor en innerText de cada celda de la tabla pero sigo sin resultados

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hay varios errores en tu forma de recorrer la tabla.

1. En el primer `for` tienes que buscar las filas con `resume_table.rows`, pero tú estas buscando con `resume_table.cells`
2. El segundo `for` está bien, pero no tienes que usar `j` para encontrar la celda, al ser dos bucles anidados, `col` será cada valor, como podrás ver en el console.log.

A partir de ahí puedes operar con tus datos, o bien optar por otra forma de lectura, dependiendo de lo que quieras lograr.

Puedes probar el código, he impreso valor, fila y celda, para que entiendas cómo funciona.

```js
var resume_table = document.getElementById("rwd-table-id");

for (var i = 0, row; row = resume_table.rows[i]; i++) {
  //alert(cell[i].innerText);
  for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
    //alert(col[j].innerText);
    console.log(`Txt: ${col.innerText} \tFila: ${i} \t Celda: ${j}`);
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="rwd-table" id="rwd-table-id">
  <tr>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Apellido</th>
    <th>Estado</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="name">Juan</td>
    <td id="apellido">Perez</td>
    <td id="status">Online</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="name">Pedro</td>
    <td id="apellido">Lopez</td>
    <td id="status">Online</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="name">Antonia</td>
    <td id="apellido">Sandoval</td>
    <td id="status">Online</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

A partir de ahí podrás operar con tu tabla, recurriendo a ciertos trucos, por ejemplo, si quieres ignorar la primera fila, sólo tienes que poner el primer bucle así:

```
for (var i = 1, row; row = resume_table.rows[i]; i++) {
```

Igualando `i` a `1`  ignorarías la primera fila. Luego, dependiendo de tu objetivo final, podría haber otras formas de acceder a ciertos valores directamente, por su posición en la tabla por ejemplo, o por su `id`.

Por ejemplo, si se trata de modificar ciertos elementos, podrías valerte también de clases CSS para eso, asignando una cierta clase a unos determinados elementos.

Comment: Me gusta mucho esta respuesta porque aporta datos en el resultado y está bien trabajada +1.

Comment: en caso que desee seleccionar solo la primer columna como seria el scrit?

Comment: @kevingarciamorales la primera columna de cada fila la tendrías en `row.cells[0]`.

Comment: sera me pueda ayudar en esta pregunta. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/546113/convertir-excel-en-html-y-despues-editarlo-en-la-vista-html/546134#546134

Answer (score 1):

De entrada hay algunas malas prácticas que sería recomendable evitar, como asignar el mismo identificado a más de un elemento. En su lugar, mejor utilizar alguna clase o atributo personalizado.

Por otro lado, la cabecera de la tabla y el cuerpo no usan las etiquetas `thead`o `tbody`, aunque no afecta, pero puede complicarte al seleccionar e iterar por los nodos de HTML.

Te dejo una aproximación:

```js
const resume_table = document.getElementById("rwd-table-id");

const tableRows = document.querySelectorAll('#rwd-table-id tr.row');

// Recorremos las filas que tengan el class="row"
// así obviamos la cabecera
for(let i=0; i<tableRows.length; i++) {
  const row = tableRows[i];
  const status = row.querySelector('.status');
  console.log('Estado: ', status.innerText);
  
  // Para modificar un estado:
  // status.innerText = 'offline';
}
```

```html
<table class="rwd-table" id="rwd-table-id">
            <tr class="header-row">
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Apellido</th>
                <th>Estado</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="row">
                <td class="name">Juan</td>
                <td class="apellido">Perez</td>
                <td class="status">Online</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="row">
                <td class="name">Pedro</td>
                <td class="apellido">Lopez</td>
                <td class="status">Online</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="row">
                <td class="name">Antonia</td>
                <td class="apellido">Sandoval</td>
                <td class="status">Online</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```