# Convertir Excel en HTML y despues editarlo en la vista HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, excel, table

estoy siguiendo una guía para crear una vista `PHP` donde subo un archivo `Exce`l y este me los `muestra en una tabla HTML` utilizando `JavaScript`. todo va bien hasta que se me ocurrió poder personalizar una de las columnas para destacarla de las demás y posterior imprimir desde el navegador. sucede que estoy intentando seleccionar la primera columna, pero no le encuentro como hacerle.

agradecería su gran ayuda de indicarme como puedo seleccionar la columna para posterior aplicar estilos css.

[image: esta es la vista de un archivo excel ya cargado en el HTML, la columna que quiero personalizar es la columna Cod]

**Este es el etiquetado HMTL y el script empleado para completar la accion**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Convertir Excel en HTML</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/xlsx@0.15.1/dist/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <link href="http://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/ccode39" rel="stylesheet">


</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="text-center mt-4 mb-4">Convertir Excel en HTML </h2>

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">Seleccione archivo Excel</div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <input type="file" id="excel_file" />

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="datos">

        <div id="excel_data" class="mt-1"></div>

    </div>

    <script>
    const excel_file = document.getElementById('excel_file');

    excel_file.addEventListener('change', (event) => {

    if(!['application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', 'application/vnd.ms-excel'].includes(event.target.files[0].type))
    {
        document.getElementById('excel_data').innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Only .xlsx or .xls file format are allowed</div>';

        excel_file.value = '';

        return false;
    }

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(event.target.files[0]);

    reader.onload = function(event){

        var data = new Uint8Array(reader.result);

        var work_book = XLSX.read(data, {type:'array'});

        var sheet_name = work_book.SheetNames;

        var sheet_data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(work_book.Sheets[sheet_name[0]], {header:1});

        if(sheet_data.length > 0)
        {
            var table_output = '<table class="table" style="table-layout:none" border="1">';
            
            for(var row = 0; row < sheet_data.length; row++)
            {
                table_output += '<tr class="thead-dark">';
                for(var cell = 0; cell < sheet_data[row].length; cell++)
                {
                    if(row == 0)
                    {
                        table_output += '<th>'+sheet_data[row][cell]+'</th>';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        table_output += '<td>'+sheet_data[row][cell]+'</td>';
                        
                    }
                }
                table_output += '</tr>';
            }
            table_output += '</table>';

            document.getElementById('excel_data').innerHTML = table_output;
        }
        excel_file.value = '';
    }

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

les agradezco de antemano
Saludos

Comment: En este bloque: `else { table_output += '<td>'+sheet_data[row][cell]+'</td>'; }` puedes agregar otro `if`, algo así: `else { if (cell == 0) { //aquí poner al td el estilo que quieras } else { table_output += '<td>'+sheet_data[row][cell]+'</td>';} }`

Comment: Excelente ahora si. Muchas Gracias. Podrias poner tu comentario como respuesta. para aceptarla como solucion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este bloque:

```
                else
                {
                    table_output += '<td>'+sheet_data[row][cell]+'</td>';
                    
                }
```

puedes agregar otro `if`, algo así:

```
                else
                {
                    if (cell == 0) {
                        //aquí poner al td el estilo que quieras
                    } else {
                        table_output += '<td>'+sheet_data[row][cell]+'</td>';
                    }                        
                }
```

O, puedes hacerlo con un ternario, en vez del `if`, algo así:

```
table_output += (cell == 0) ? "aquí td cuando sea la 1ª columna" : '<td>'+sheet_data[row][cell]+'</td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Si no tienes como aplicar un formato a las celdas de la tabla desde su creación, entonces tendrás que hacerlo después de creada, recorriendo fila por fila y aplicándole el estilo a la celda que necesites de cada una de las filas. Te dejo un enlace donde se explica como recorrer la tabla.

[Como recorrer una tabla de HTML con JAVASCRIPT](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/425986/como-recorrer-una-tabla-de-html-con-javascript)